How to send form-data parameters in Apache benchmark testing
How to send request from apache benchmark tool.
Following is the curl syntax
curl -X 'POST' /usecase/run_usecase_fromvs -H 'accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' -F 'usecase_name=Code Generation' -F 'user_input=Generate function to add two numbers' -F 'language=py' -F 'token=Xenius_df227a0a-c79f-45fa-9c5a-69ab34729159' -F 'llmguard=false'

I tridd -p flag but it was not working. Want to do benchmarking of the url.
